# yeoman: grunt server waiting... can't go back to command line

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I installed yeoman, and trying use command: grunt server to preview my application.
everything is fine except when i try to get back to command line to continue typing in some commands, below is the status after i run grunt server:

```
Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
Prefixed file ".tmp/styles/main.css" created.

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on 127.0.0.1:9000.

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

does anybody know how to stop it?

Comment: May I know how you solved this problem? and this my question, check please..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874258/node-js-running-watch-default-task-waiting

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is intentional; the Yeoman generated `grunt server` command gives you a complete testing environment so that you can have files being compiled and a server to preview your app on. If you stop it, you'll have to start it again with the same command. I'd recommend using something like http://www.iterm2.com/ if you're on a Mac so that you can keep the process running in a separate window, that way you don't have to keep stopping/starting it.

Nonetheless, you can stop the task at any time with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Please check..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874258/node-js-running-watch-default-task-waiting