# node.js - Running "watch_default" task waiting

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

1.**grunt** in terminal, showing:

[image]

Then I just follow the terminal commend,

First, running `grunt build --env uat`, then running successful.

After that, running `grunt watch --evn uat`, but in `Running "watch_default" task` step, showing **waiting** but will not go to next step.
[image]

And I try run `grunt test`, showing this error for me.
[image]

I tried to search in google, but still don't have a good solution to solve this problem.

This is the reference:

1.[[Watch] Waiting... never OK #474](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/474)

2.[Grunt watch Running “watch” task Waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371344/grunt-watch-running-watch-task-waiting)

3.[Trying to run a Grunt watch task but it just says Waiting... and never resolves?](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/2y2r6b/trying_to_run_a_grunt_watch_task_but_it_just_says/)

UPDATE:

```
## Custom tasks ------------------------------------------------------------

    grunt.task.renameTask "watch", "watch_default"

    grunt.registerTask "default", "Usage", usage

    grunt.registerTask "scripts", "Compiles the JavaScript files.", [
        "clean:scripts"
        "coffee:all"
        "coffee:env"
        "browserify:all"
        "clean:temp"
    ].concat unless Debug then ["uglify:all"] else []

    grunt.registerTask "stylesheets", "Compiles the stylesheets.", [
        "clean:stylesheets"
        "stylus:all"
        "autoprefixer:all"
    ].concat unless Debug then ["cssmin"] else []

    grunt.registerTask "test", "Run unit testing.", ->
        grunt.fail.fatal "Unit testing is not implemented yet" # TODO

    grunt.registerTask "build", "Compiles all of the assets and copies the files to the Build directory.", [
        "clean:all"
        "copy:static"
        "jade:all"
        "htmlmin:all"
        "stylesheets"
        "scripts"
    ].concat unless Debug then ["clean:production"] else []

    grunt.registerTask "watch", "Builds and watches the project for changes.", [
        "build"
        "watch_default"
    ]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have custom grunt.js file? If yes, then please provide that.

Comment: @SanketBajoria Sure..but this is not my project, so may I know how to find grunt.js

Comment: @SanketBajoria I got one file called `gruntfile.coffee`

Comment: yes, this one...

Comment: @SanketBajoria Is it this one? check, please.

Comment: @SanketBajoria Is it update correct?

Comment: Is it creating a loop.. i can see watch has been renamed to watch_default.. and then watch is calling watch_default

Comment: @SanketBajoria So how should I change it?

Comment: Actually I just want to open this project, but I try `grunt test` in terminal also cannot running.

Comment: Actually test is not implemented, as you can see in gruntfile.coffee. What i can see in gruntfile.coffee, it is just compiling jade to html, coffee to js, sass to css, then uglify and then browserify. But, actually it is not running any server, which can serve any webpage. Please let me know, if there any tasks folder, or any other instruction given to run this

Comment: Please share the codebase if possible, it's very hard to tell, from image. What is written in uat.litcoffee file. Does documentation folder contain anything

Comment: But I cannot open uat.litcoffee...