# grunt test - Fatal error: Unit testing is not implemented yet

Tags: angularjs, node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-jade

I already setup the project environment, and install grunt succeed. In terminal I tried run `grunt` that showing this for me:

[image]

Then I follow the step.

1. grunt build --env uat (this step running succeed)
2. grunt watch --env uat (this step got problem and I post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874258/node-js-running-watch-default-task-waiting))
3. grunt test (this step showing error for me: **Fatal error: Unit testing is not implemented yet**)

[image]

This project include: angularJS, jade, coffeescript, I already setup all environment, but still don't know how to run this project.

```
###
    Build script for ** project.

    USAGE INSTRUCTIONS:
    Run `grunt` on the command line, from the same directory as this file
    or any subfolder to see usage instructions.

    TODO:
    - Fix totally broken `--debug` mode.
    - Unit testing support.
###

module.exports = (grunt) ->

    ## Config ------------------------------------------------------------------

    Instructions = """
        Usage:
        1) Build all files once.
            grunt build --env Environment [--debug]
        2) Builds files and automatically re-build when any file changes are detected.
            grunt watch --env Environment [--debug]
        3) Builds and runs Unit Tests.
            grunt test

        Where:
        - debug: to compile for development (leave out to compile for production)
        - Environment can be the filenam (minus extension) of any environment
          file in the Environments/ directory.
    """


    ## Command Line options ----------------------------------------------------

    Debug = grunt.option("debug")?
    Env = grunt.option("env")

    if grunt.cli.tasks.length and grunt.cli.tasks[0] isnt "test"
        unless Env? and grunt.file.exists "Environments/#{Env}.litcoffee"
            grunt.fail.fatal "Please specify a valid environment!"
            return


    ## Helpers -----------------------------------------------------------------

    usage = ->
        grunt.log.writeln Instructions


    ## Grunt config ------------------------------------------------------------

    grunt.initConfig

        autoprefixer:
            options:
                browsers: ["last 3 versions"]
                map:
                    inline: false
            all:
                expand: true
                cwd: "Build"
                src: ["*.css"]
                dest: "Build"

        browserify:
            all:
                expand: true
                cwd: "Build/Temp/CoffeeTemp"
                src: ["*.js"]
                dest: "Build"
                ext: ".js"

        clean:
            all:
                src: ["Build"]
            temp:
                src: ["Build/Temp"]
            production: [
                "Build/**/*.js.map"
                "Build/**/*.css.map"
            ]
            stylesheets:
                src: ["Build/*.css"]
            scripts:
                src: ["Build/*.js"]
            jade:
                src: [
                    "Build/*.html"
                    "Build/templates/**/*.html"
                ]

        coffee:
            options:
                bare: true
                # sourceMap: Debug
            env:
                src: ["Environments/#{Env}.litcoffee"]
                dest: "Build/Temp/CoffeeTemp/services/env.js"
            all:
                expand: true
                cwd: "Source Code"
                src: ["**/*.litcoffee"]
                dest: "Build/Temp/CoffeeTemp"
                ext: ".js"

        copy:
            static:
                expand: true
                cwd: "Source Code"
                src: [ "static/**/*" ]
                dest: "Build"

        cssmin:
            options:
                sourceMap: true
            build:
                expand: true
                cwd: "Build"
                src: ["*.css"]
                dest: "Build"

        htmlmin:
            all:
                options:
                    removeComments: true
                    collapseWhitespace: true
                    conservativeCollapse: true
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true
                        cwd: "Build"
                        src: [
                            "*.html",
                            "templates/**/*.html"
                        ]
                        dest: "Build"
                        ext: ".html"
                        filter: "isFile"
                    }
                ]

        jade:
            options:
                doctype: "html" # keeps attributes with no value as-is (i.e.
                    # prevents div(md-raised) from becoming
                    # <div md-raised="md-raised">...)
                data: {}
                pretty: false
            all:
                files: [
                    expand: true
                    cwd: "Source Code"
                    src: [
                        "*.jade"
                        "admin/*.jade"
                        "activate/*.jade"
                        "activation/*.jade"
                        "cargoTrackingMobile/*.jade"
                        "templates/**/*.jade"
                    ]
                    dest: "Build"
                    ext: ".html"
                ]

        stylus:
            all:
                options:
                    linenos: true
                    compress: !Debug
                    sourcemap:
                        comment: true
                        inline: false
                        sourceRoot: "."
                        basePath: "."
                files: [
                    expand: true
                    cwd: "Source Code/styles"
                    src: [
                        "**/*.styl"
                        "!**/_*.styl"
                    ]
                    dest: "Build"
                    ext: ".css"
                ]

        uglify:
            options:
                mangle: {}
                sourceMap: Debug
            all:
                expand: true
                cwd: "Build"
                src: ["*.js"]
                dest: "Build"

        watch_default:
            scripts:
                files: [
                    "Source Code/*.litcoffee"
                    "Source Code/**/*.litcoffee"
                    "!Source Code/static/**/*.litcoffee"
                ]
                tasks: ["scripts"]
            stylesheets:
                files: ["Source Code/styles/**/*"]
                tasks: ["stylesheets"]
            html:
                files: [
                    "Source Code/*.jade"
                    "Source Code/admin/*.jade"
                    "Source Code/activate/*.jade"
                    "Source Code/activation/*.jade"
                    "Source Code/cargoTrackingMobile/*.jade"
                    "Source Code/templates/**/*.jade"
                ]
                tasks: ["jade:all"]
            static:
                files: ["Source Code/static/**/*"]
                tasks: ["copy:static"]

    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-autoprefixer"
    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-browserify"
    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-clean"
    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-coffee"
    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-copy"
    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-cssmin"
    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-htmlmin"
    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-jade"
    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-stylus"
    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-uglify"
    grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-watch"


    ## Custom tasks ------------------------------------------------------------

    grunt.task.renameTask "watch", "watch_default"

    grunt.registerTask "default", "Usage", usage

    grunt.registerTask "scripts", "Compiles the JavaScript files.", [
        "clean:scripts"
        "coffee:all"
        "coffee:env"
        "browserify:all"
        "clean:temp"
    ].concat unless Debug then ["uglify:all"] else []

    grunt.registerTask "stylesheets", "Compiles the stylesheets.", [
        "clean:stylesheets"
        "stylus:all"
        "autoprefixer:all"
    ].concat unless Debug then ["cssmin"] else []

    grunt.registerTask "test", "Run unit testing.", ->
        grunt.fail.fatal "Unit testing is not implemented yet" # TODO

    grunt.registerTask "build", "Compiles all of the assets and copies the files to the Build directory.", [
        "clean:all"
        "copy:static"
        "jade:all"
        "htmlmin:all"
        "stylesheets"
        "scripts"
    ].concat unless Debug then ["clean:production"] else []

    grunt.registerTask "watch", "Builds and watches the project for changes.", [
        "build"
        "watch_default"
    ]
```

Comment: You need to include your gruntfile, otherwise we don't know what library / code your test task is using

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech So you mean I have to upload the `gruntfile.coffee` file first, right?

Comment: Yes, this is where you have defined the `test` task. Otherwise we have no idea what may be causing your error.

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech Actually no `test` in gruntfile.coffee file, I just follow grunt command showing that using `grunt test` for launch the project..and I already update grunt file in my question, check please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is raising an error because that is how this task is defined in your `gruntfile.coffee`:

```
grunt.registerTask "test", "Run unit testing.", ->
    grunt.fail.fatal "Unit testing is not implemented yet" # TODO
```

Ask whomever maintains this project for more details.

Comment: May I know what should I get from the developer?

Comment: My guess is that the instructions and tasks in that gruntfile are incomplete or outdated. Ask for clarification on if there are any tests, and if so how they can be run.